# What are the performance costs/considerations when pinning memory in c#/.net

Tags: c#, opengl, marshalling

**Context:**

I have a c# opengl desktop app.
We have various buffers that get updated every frame, and so need to be transferred to the GPU every frame.

Currently we are holding a single pin to each buffer for the lifetime of the application, but I'm wondering if it would be significantly slower to just pin for each transfer (so every frame for each buffer), say using a fixed block.

This would have benefits for our code manageability as we aren't needing to store multiple objects/values per buffer, and don't need to worry about explicit clean up (freeing the pinned handle).

We effectively have a buffer per entity type. So talking about a couple dozen buffers total max, though these buffers could be quite big, multiple GB each.

**Question:**

What are the performance considerations/costs of pinning memory (esp big arrays, some of which will end up on the LOH)?
Is there a performance difference between using a fixed block, and using GHHandle Alloc / AddrOfPinnedObject / Free?

Comment: What do you mean by "pinning"? Do you mean mapping (as in `glMapBufferRange`) or do you mean the GL_AMD_pinned_memory extension?

Comment: I mean pinning managed memory (.net) so that it can be used by unmanaged code (open gl) For example using a fixed() block, or GCHandle

Comment: Using `fixed` is fast, whereas `GCHandle.Alloc` is terribly slow and it doesn't even work with non-blittable types (including `bool,` `char`, `decimal`, `DateTime`, etc.).

Comment: You are *required* to pin on data transfers,  otherwise you'll have bad times...

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-1-layout/) the .net object headers contain:

> Special flag that notifies GC that an object is pinned and should not be moved during garbage collection.

So I would expect the pinning to simply set or unset this flag, and that should only be a few instructions. It may involve taking a lock if concurrent GC is used, and that could have some impact if it has to wait for the lock. But I don't know the internals of the GC to that level of detail.

The typical reason not to pin memory is that it will prevent compaction of memory, and can therefore lead to memory fragmentation. But if your buffers are larger than 85kb they will be on the large object heap (LOH), and this will not be automatically compacted anyway. So I would not expect any real impact due to fragmentation.

But as with anything regarding performance, measure. I can make guesses about performance, but I might very well be wrong. So I would recommend benchmarking your application before and after the change. You could also consider writing a micro-benchmark if you want to test the idea before spending a lot of time refactoring your application.